# iTunes connect: Set Extra price for update for existing user of application

Tags: app-store-connect, updates

I already submit a application on app store which have price  $6.99. Now I am submitting new version of this app. Here I want that iPhone user, which already installed this application, should pay $.99 for this update and new user should pay $6.99

Is it possible to charge extra amount for existing user for update ? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

No. Updates from the App Store are always free. If you wish to charge for additional content, you can use the In-App purchasing system.

Otherwise, your only option is to create an entirely new App for major updates if you wish to get more money from your users.